# R Error: replacement diagonal has wrong length

Tags: r, rpy2

I am trying to debug this line of R code, which was written in and works with R version 2.3.x and called in using rpy but now moving to 2.15.3, and rpy2, it seems to be broken? My matrix is quite large, it is a length 409x409., and the diagonals are filled with floating integers (I think?).  I am looking at the raw matrix file that is pulled in and the diags are filled with 99999.00.  The rest of the cells are in the format of ##.##

The offending line of code in question:

```
diag(mymatrix) <- apply(mymatrix, 1, function(x) min(x[x>0], na.rm=T)) * 0.73
```

returns the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 166, in **call**
>       return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).**call**(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 99, in **call**
>       res = super(Function, self).**call**(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
>   RRuntimeError: Error in `diag<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(72999.27, 1.39576, 2.79616323829879,  : 
>     replacement diagonal has wrong length

I looked at [the SVN.R website](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/base/R/diag.R) to see the inner workings of the `diag`function, to see where the error is coming from:

```
if (len.v != 1L && len.v != len.i)
stop("replacement diagonal has wrong length")
```

I think that tells me my answer right there, my replacement value is not the proper length, right?  So how do I go about getting my replacement diagonal to the proper length for this to "stick"?

**EDIT --Added context for troubleshooting purposes--**

This matrix is initially generated as an 409x409 array (using numpy) through a Python script and assigned using `ro.r.assign`.  Then, in my R script, `mymatrix` was originally (in the R version 2.3.1 form) called in using:

`mymatrix <- do.call("rbind", mymatrix)`

But now in 2.15.3 and Rpy2, I got an error using this do.call on the array.  It would give me the following error:

> File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 166, in **call**
>       return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).**call**(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 99, in **call**
>       res = super(Function, self).**call**(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
>   RRuntimeError: Error in do.call("rbind", mymatrix) : second argument must be a list

So my "fix" for this was to simply use `as.list` to convert it to a list as written below:

`mymatrix <- do.call("rbind", as.list(mymatrix))`

But now thinking about this further, it occurs to me that maybe this is the problem.  Do I need to convert this back again for the diagonal to work correctly, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: how many values does the apply function return? are there NAs in mymatrix?

Comment: That is a good question.  Could you please read my **EDIT** above, for additional context?  There are NAs in the matrix, but they are passed through initially as a numpy array.  However, I encountered issues with this and converted it to a list. It could be that I need to re-transform it and then perform the diagonal, but that is where I am lost.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, as.list(mymatrix))` would transform your square, [409 by 409] matrix into a [409*409 by 1] matrix, so that is most likely a problem. why did you try to do.call rbind anyway?

Comment: Ah..so how can I re-transform it? Also, is there a better way than do.call rbind?  I did not write this code --it was written about 10 years ago by someone else.  I am trying my best to learn R and Python and all these things through cleaning this code up and in the process, debug my model. :/

Comment: at that line, if mymatrix is already a matrix, then there is no point in rbinding anything. what is the `str(mymatrix)` before that line? I have not been using r for very long, so I couldn't say how do.call was working before the change that broke this code

Comment: 'num [1:409, 1:409] 1.00e+05 1.91 3.83 1.11e+01 1.19e+01 ...' is what I get

Comment: smells like a matrix. so what happens when you commented that line out?

Comment: Yep. There are 12 other matrices that all have the same issue and same diag function applied, so the problem has propogated itself throughout the entire script.  Further, I need to bind these matrices somehow in order to bring in the matrices that are generated by the model.  From Python, they are saved to an .RData workspace image, and then pulled in by this R script with the `do.call` and the `diag` functions.

Comment: But let me reiterate that that is the structure in its raw form. In order to perform do.call on it, I have to convert it to a list using `as.list`.  However, either way it is presented to R (as a list or matrix), that `diag` function as written is still returning the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rawr pointed out, `do.call(rbind, as.list(mymatrix))` returns a 409x409 by 1 matrix, and thus, the diagonal function could not be formulated correctly.  The solution was to replace `do.call` with `rbind.fill` via the R package `plyr`, which successfully brought in the matrix in its proper form, and then the `diag` function performed the way it should.

Comment: I will also add that plyr is very useful and speeds performance up quite a bit when manipulating matrices within R!